# How to transfer the date string from my DatePickerFragment?

Tags: java, android

I get this source from another question in stackoverflow..

this is my fragment.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#e1e1e1">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="#fff">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Set Reminder"
                        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:textColor="#009cee"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#e1e1e1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Range Hari"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>


                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:id="@+id/range"
                        android:ems="10" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Tanggal Awal"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:background="#fff">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:id="@+id/tanggalawaltxt"
                        android:ems="10" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="#EC407A"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:text="Set Tanggal"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:id="@+id/tanggal"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:background="#fff">


                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#009cee"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:text="Simpan"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:id="@+id/simpan"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my DatePickerFragment.java

```html
package com.example.gandi.symanlub;

/**
 * Created by mgd on 10/07/16.
 */



public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, day);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    }
}
```

and this is my setreminder.java

```html
package com.example.gandi.symanlub;


public class Setreminder extends Fragment {


    Button btnshowtanggal;
    TextView tanggalawal;
    View rootview;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setreminder, container, false);

        btnshowtanggal = (Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.tanggal);
        btnshowtanggal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
                picker.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

                tanggalawal = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tanggalawaltxt);

            }
        });

        return rootview;

    }



}
```

How to get the string of Datetimepicker selected date into tanggalawal (TextView) ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Make an interface in your SetReminder called DateListener with a method onDateSelected(Date date);

2) Make any Activity using the SetReminder Fragment to implement an interface SetReminder.DateListener.

3) In onAttach(Activity activity) in your SetReminder Fragment, check if the attaching Activity implements that SetReminder.DateListener, and if so intitalize your Fragment's DateListener.

4) Normally you'd want to extend your flow a bit, and maybe add a confirmation button by adding an AlertDialog before you actually call onDateSet on your listener.  In your case though, you could just call onDateSelected(Date date), add a delegate callback to your activity by calling

```
if (mDateListener != null){
   mDateListener.onDateSelected(calendar.getTime());
}
```

EDIT: for Dialog code example...you should be able to figure out how to implement the provided interface in your Activity and set it on the view that's listening for date updates.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

public interface DateTimePickedListener {
        void onDateTimePicked(String formattedDate);
    }

    DateTimePickedListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if(activity instanceof DateTimePickedListener){
            listener = (DateTimePickedListener) activity;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, day);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        if(listener != null){
            listener.onDateSelected(formattedDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you answer by example code? sorry because I am really newbie in android or java..

Comment: Editted for an example of the dialog, the rest should be self explanatory